# Include a PDF and ignore page margins?

Tags: margins, include, pdfpages

I am writing a document using `pdfLaTeX` for college, and I have been supplied with a title page I need to use.

I have altered the `\maketitle` command:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \includepdf{title.pdf}
}
```

It does what it is supposed to do, but there's one problem: LaTeX seems to add a margin to the bottom/right of the page, so that the top/left part of the title page does not fit on the page.

To illustrate: on the left is what I want (the blue part being the contents of `title.pdf`), on the right is what I'm getting.

[image: On the left is what I need, on the right is what I have.]

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the included PDF exactly the same size as your document? Otherwise, please post a minimal example that we can copy'n'paste

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\begin{picture}(0,0)` means the whole construct takes up no space as far as TeX is concerned, change the `(10,10)` coordinates to move the insert to an arbitrary position on the page, whatever looks right.

It appears that `\includepdf` doesn't like `picture` mode. Not sure why. The standard `\includegraphics` works though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)\put(10,10){\includegraphics{title.pdf}}\end{picture}%
   \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

original version:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

...

```
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)\put(10,10){\includepdf{title.pdf}}\end{picture}%
   \clearpage
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use an additional package for this? I'm getting an `! Undefined control sequence.` error when I try this.

Comment: You only need package to define `\includepdf` that you used in your initial example (or you could use the standard graphicx package and `\includegraphics{title.pdf}` if you prefer. The picture environment is standard latex. (This is why you should always put complete document not just fragments in your question)

Comment: I solved part of the problem. Your post closes `\put`'s parameters with `}` instead of `)`. You might want to correct that in that your post to help people like me who use copy+paste a lot. :) However, there still seems to be something strange going on with the `\put` command. When I remove it, it correctly includes `title.pdf`, though placing it wrong. But with `\put` there, the compiler says `Missing \endgroup inserted`. I read that this means that there's a nesting of environments that's not allowed, but I see what it can be. `picture` is only inside `document` here.

Comment: @ArnoSluismans see update.